# Where I can learn algorithms or and find examples of code for controlling a rover?

Tags: mobile-robot, algorithm, pwm, c

I am a programmer by profession and new to Robotics. I have studied ECE, so know electronics, but not very familiar with mechanical aspects of robotics. I am working on a learning project with Dagu Rover 5 platform.

I am trying to control the 4 DC motors with PWM and want to use the optical encoders for feedback. I am looking for some algorithms, example code in C to effectively control the rover. I know how to control the GPIO, PWM and interrupts from the processor. I am more interested in learning the algorithm that controls the motors based on this. For now, i am working on a manual robot, controlled with up/down/left/right keys. In future, I would like to add sensors, camera etc and work on autonomous aspects. Any pointers would be helpful.

For reference, I am working on the Raspberry Pi platform to control the rover.

Comment: The word "control" can mean a lot of things in robotics. For instance are you asking how you send commands to the robot or how ensure the motors do what you intend them to do?

Comment: This question needs a bit more focus.  What specific thing would you like the robot to do?  That will guide the choice of algorithm.

Comment: you could be more specific in the project you are creating? what are the skills you want the robot? logarithms are many that can be used. I would like to accompany you

Comment: On Robotics, we prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it is a good idea to include details of what what you would like to achieve, what you have tried, what you expected to see & what you actually saw. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically about control of motors by PWM, you should learn about the [PID controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller).

The sky's the limit for what you want to learn about.  Find a robotics simulator to start playing around with algorithms -- otherwise you will find that you will spend all year building the robot instead.

For a mobile robot, motion planning or mapping algorithms would be a good start.

Real sensors are noisy and ambiguous, so machine learning (i.e. statistical, fuzzy learning) is a whole field you can look at if you're interested, with applications in control, motion planning, and vision processing.  How much time do you have?

Comment: Thanks..! Can you point me to some online material which is good for beginners?